# Proving a process is martingale under the Risk Neutral Measure

Tags: options, black-scholes, risk-neutral-measure, martingale

Show that for any $\lambda \in \Re$, the process $Y_{\lambda,t}$ defined as:

$$Y_{\lambda,t} = (S_t/S_0)^\lambda e^{-(r\lambda-\lambda(1-\lambda)\sigma^2/2)t}$$

is a martingale under the risk neutral measure $Q$.

I was thinking that I could apply Ito's Lemma, in which to show that the $\text{d}t$ term will be zero. However, after doing the partial derivatives, the terms do not cancel each other out.

Would really appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: What dynamics does $S_t$ follow? What is $x$ and $\lambda$? Your exponential is unclear too.

Comment: I have amended your equation to what I believe is the proper expression, and provided an answer based on that. Can you confirm that my correction is correct?

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw Sorry, I made a mistake! It's supposed to be 2 and not $x$! $S_t$ follows the dynamics of the Black & Scholes model!

Comment: Ok, that is what I was wondering. You can check my answer below, I assume $S_t$ follows lognormal dynamics (i.e. as in the Black-Scholes model) with drift $r$ and diffusion/volatility $\sigma$ then?

Comment: Find the partial derivative with respect to t & S and plug it into Ito's lemma. Then use the fact that $S_t$ follows the black scholes model $dS_t=S_t(rdt+\sigma dW_t)$ and plug it back into $dS_t and (dS_t)^2$ should help in cancelling out the dt terms and you'll be left with only the $dW_t$ terms.

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Comment: Note that $S_t = S_0\exp\big((r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t + \sigma W_t\big)$. Then $Y_{\lambda, t} = \exp\big(-\frac{(\lambda\sigma)^2}{2}t + \lambda\sigma W_t\big)$ is obviously a martingale.

Answer (score 2):

We define the process $Y_t=Y(t,S_t)$ as follows:
$$Y_t=\left(\frac{S_t}{S_0}\right)^\lambda \exp\left\{-\left(r\lambda-\lambda(1-\lambda)\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t\right\}$$

**Method 1**

Let:
$$\alpha=\lambda\left(r-(1-\lambda)\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)$$
Then by Itô's Lemma:
$$\text{d}Y_t=-\alpha Y_t\text{d}t+\frac{\lambda}{S_t}Y_t\text{d}S_t+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\lambda(\lambda-1)}{S_t^2}Y_t\text{d}\langle S_t,S_t\rangle$$
Assuming $S_t$ follows a Geometric Brownian Motion with drift $\mu$ and diffusion $\beta$:
$$\text{d}S_t=\mu S_t\text{d}t+\beta S_t\text{d}W_t$$
Then:
$$\text{d}Y_t=\left(\lambda\mu+\lambda(\lambda-1)\frac{\beta^2}{2}-\alpha\right)Y_t\text{d}t+\lambda\beta Y_t\text{d}W_t$$
Hence for $Y_t$ to be a (local) martingale we need:
$$\lambda\mu+\lambda(\lambda-1)\frac{\beta^2}{2}=r\lambda+\lambda(\lambda-1)\frac{\sigma^2}{2}$$
This is true if:
$$\begin{align}
\text{C.1}\quad\mu&=r\\
\text{C.2}\quad\beta&=\sigma
\end{align}$$

**Method 2**

Note also that, if the above conditions $\text{C.1}$ and $\text{C.2}$ hold:
$$\begin{align}
Y_t&=\left(\frac{S_t}{S_0}\right)^\lambda \exp\left\{-\left(r\lambda-\lambda(1-\lambda)\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t\right\}
\\
&=\exp\left\{\left(r\lambda-\lambda\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t+\lambda\sigma W_t\right\}\exp\left\{-\left(r\lambda-\lambda(1-\lambda)\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t\right\}
\\
&=\exp\left\{-\lambda^2\frac{\sigma^2}{2}t+\lambda\sigma W_t\right\}
\end{align}$$
Let $0<s<t$. Then:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb E^Q\left[Y(t,S_t)|\mathcal{F}_s\right]&= \exp\left\{-\lambda^2\frac{\sigma^2}{2}s+\lambda\sigma W_s\right\}\mathbb E^Q\left[\exp\left\{-\lambda^2\frac{\sigma^2}{2}(t-s)+\lambda\sigma (W_t-W_s)\right\}|\mathcal F_s\right] 
\\
&= \exp\left\{-\lambda^2\frac{\sigma^2}{2}s+\lambda\sigma W_s\right\}\mathbb E^Q\left[\exp\left\{-\lambda^2\frac{\sigma^2}{2}(t-s)+\lambda\sigma (W_t-W_s)\right\}\right] 
\\
&= \exp\left\{-\lambda^2\frac{\sigma^2}{2}s+\lambda\sigma W_s\right\}
\\[7pt]
&= Y_s
\end{align}$$

Comment: Do we assume the expected value under Q of the line just before the last one is 0 because expected value of $W_t - W_s$ is 0 ? If it the case, how does it cancel the all exponential ?

Comment: @TmSmth $W_t-W_s$ is a normally-distributed random variable with $0$ expectation and variance $\lambda^2\sigma^2(t-s)$ thus its [Laplace transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1540880/laplace-transform-of-normal-distribution-function) is $\exp\{(\lambda^2\sigma^2(t-s))/2\}$, hence terms cancel and we get $e^0=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$E_0[Y_{\lambda,t}] = 1\,\, \forall t$, hence $Y_t$ is a martingale.

Hint: Look at the arithmetic moments section of [this wiki page on lognormal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution)